# How do I make sure that the Yosemite icon for the Time Machine Disk on my desktop shows the updated version and not the Mavericks version?

Tags: icon, macos

[image: icons for external drives]

As you can see in the images the icon for the external drive Quetzalcoatl has update to the Yosemite version, however the Time Machine disk hasn't. Is it possible to force the use of the new icon?

Comment: Are you sure there is a new icon? I think that's the standard for Yosemite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: There is nothing wrong here.

[image: What it should look like]

Under */Volumes/*, there are two type of mounted volumes associated with Time Machine:

First is the hard drive the backup sits on. If you use Time Capsule, the hard drive inside is by default called *Data*. Because it's access through network, the volume in the picture has a Shared Disk icon. If you use an external drive through USB, the volume would have a USB/External icon.

Inside, there is a file with name like *Someone's Macbook Something.sparsebundle*. When backing up, Time Machine would mount this file and create */Volumes/Time Machine Backups*. This volume is covered with Time Machine icon, and it only appears with TM is running. The name cannot be altered as far as I know

My conjecture is that *Budda* in question is a volume of a hard drive, not the mounted volume of the sparsebundle. Like other files, volumes can have its icon changed through Get Info window, which is probably why a generic disk got a TM icon in the first place.

Cut and paste the new icon from the location below, and you will have this resolved.

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/
```

[image: Icon Location]

Comment: Could you expand this answer to include how to set this icon as the icon used?

Comment: @grgarside I did a little more thinking.

Answer (score 2):

I see the incorrect icon displayed every so often with Yosemite and El Capitan.

This is always fixed for me by *relaunching* the Finder - one way of doing that is holding down Alt, then right clicking on the Finder icon in the dock, and then clicking relaunch.  After that the correct icon is shown on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the right one from here & paste it in...

[Yosemite drive icon pack](http://ziggy19.deviantart.com/art/OS-X-Yosemite-Drives-476685369)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click the drive > get info > click on the (old) icon > backspace (or delete) > done.